# Feature extraction from a Video using Matlab

Tags: matlab

My FYP has supervisor asked me to search for methods to extract feature vectors from a video. As I am totally new to image processing concepts, I am totally confused. I'll be working on MATLAB. 
Which direction should I be moving in? What algorithms are used to extract features?

Comment: What are you trying to do with these features?

Comment: I am working on extracting hand signs from a video. I will use the output and will compare it against some stored value.

Comment: How can I extract features from a video using MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

The type of features you choose will depend on the number of videos you have. You will likely need to build a processing pipeline. I would suggest looking at:

- canny edge detection
- hough line transform.
- histogram features over rectangles after processing.

If you have a large dataset you might consider using a lower bias model with more features. If you have a small dataset, consider higher bias with less features.

If you have a really huge dataset you might consider using raw pixel values (maybe at a reduced resolution) and a convolutional neural network.